# Why does function not return var `db` to next function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, class

```
class Database: 
    def set_db_setting(self, host, username, passwd, database):
        try:
            db = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=username, passwd=passwd, db=database)
        except:
            print('\nerror connecting to database\n')
    return db
```

**Function where it fails**

```
    def db_select(self, *selected_fields, **kwargs):
        self.selected_fields = selected_fields = list(selected_fields)
        self.table = (kwargs['table']
                      if 'table' in kwargs 
                      else selected_fields.pop())

        self.where_field = (kwargs['where_field']
                            if 'where_field' in kwargs
                            else selected_fields.pop())
        try:
            with db.cursor() as cursor:
                sql_tld_id_query = Database.query_stmt_list[0]+ selected_fields + Database.query_stmt_list[4] + table + Database.query_stmt_list[5] + where_field + '=' + 'www.website.com'

        except Exception as gatherid_err:
            print("exception was {}".format(gatherid_err))
            db.rollback()
```

When I instantiate at the end it fails:

```
dbclass = Database()
dbclass.set_db_setting('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'garbagedb')
dbclass.db_select(['id', 'name'], table='tld', where_field='name')
```

**UPDATED ERROR**

```
exception was Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

On this line:

```
sql_tld_id_query = Database.query_stmt_list[0]+ selected_fields + Database.query_stmt_list[4] + table + Database.query_stmt_list[5] + where_field + '=' + 'www.website.com'
```

I tried changing this to:

```
sql_tld_id_query = str(Database.query_stmt_list[0]+ selected_fields + Database.query_stmt_list[4] + table + Database.query_stmt_list[5] + where_field + '=' + 'www.ebay.com')
```

but this doesnt fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: In `set_db_setting`, if the `try` fails the assignment to `db` doesn't happen.

Comment: Because of bad indentation, your `return db` is not even a part of the function.

Comment: The indentation of return is outside function definition

Comment: Also, the `db` is local to the function `set_db_setting`. You need to set `self.db = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, indentation is important. The return statement isn't inside `set_db_setting()` so it's not returning anything.

Secondly, variables defined inside a function have a *scope* that is limited to the inside of the function so `db` doesn't magically get transported between the two method calls.  You either want to store it in `self.db` (and refer to it as such in `db_select()` or you want to return it from `set_db_setting()`, store it in a local variable, and then explicitly pass **that** into `db_select()` as an argument.

Using `self.db` & storing it as an instance variable would be the more conventional way of writing the code.

Comment: Am i then doing `return self.db` of just `return db`  for `set_db_setting` ?

Comment: @Jshee - you'd say `self.db = pymsql.connect...` and you don't need to return anything.  You're making it an attribute of the class.

Comment: Then refer to `self.db` throughout the class?

Comment: @Jshee - you're saying `str(someString + selected_fields)`.  Since `selected_fields` is a list & not a string, you can't just add it to a string without first converting it to a string.  I suggest putting your SQL string into a variable so you can print it & debug easier.

Comment: @Jshee You should accept one of the answers for this question and create a new one for your query error.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't appear to set a class variable called db.  It simply returns that value.  Then in your class you're trying to access a variable that hasn't been set.

I believe you need something like this.

```
class Database: 
    db = None
    def set_db_setting(self, host, username, passwd, database):
        try:
            self.db = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=username, passwd=passwd, db=database)
        except:
            print('\nerror connecting to database\n')
```

Now that the variable is set your other methods in the class can access it.

Comment: is db = None required? how is self.db accessed outside the function?

Comment: @Jshee That's just declaring the variable, then in your `set_db_setting` method you're giving it an actual value.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you revealed

here you discard the result of the call (which is what you return by "return db")

```
dbclass.set_db_setting('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'garbagedb')
```

and here you are calling what you'd never instantiated:

```
def db_select(self, *selected_fields, **kwargs):
   ...
   with db.cursor() as cursor:
   ...
   db.rollback()
```

so what are you wondering about?

Then, even if you don't forget to assign the call result to the variable - you didn't pass it to second function.
That means, you'd be using it as global variable.

And that's definitely a duke, if not a king, among anti-patterns.
Avoid that by all means.

PS And learn what the variable scope is.